# How to add image rollover to Javascript

Tags: javascript, hover

I have an image that when clicked hidden content is shown and it switches to a different image, and when clicked again it reverts to its normal state. I'm using a bit of code I found on this site and it works great. I would like to add a rollover to the image as well. Im stumped on how to do this, as I am not very well versed in javascript. Any help is appreciated.

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var imageNo = 2;
function swapImage() {
image = document.getElementById('image')
switch (imageNo) {
 case 1:
   image.src = "images/img.png"
   imageNo = 2
   document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'none'
   return(false);
case 2:
   image.src = "images/img1.png"
   imageNo = 1
    document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block'
    return(false);
}
}
</script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <h4><a href="#"><img id="image" name="image" src="images/img.png" border="0" onclick="swapImage();"/></a></h4>
  <div id="content" style="display:none">This content toggles</span>
 </body><code>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AGgha/3/.
 
It uses jQuery ( http://jquery.com/),which makes your js dev much easier and lets you animate your divs.
It uses the setInterval for infinte swaping as you're on the img. I've also added some improvements of your code for making it a bit better use it if you want.

Comment: whoa, Im a newbie to html and this is a bit over my head. I played with that code a bit but i really dont know what im doing. How do you make it not cycle through the images when hovering? Is it possible only to show the content once the image is clicked?

Comment: if you seee the fiddle there are the mouseIn/mouseOut functions where they do a setInterval, where you pass a function and a quantity of milliseconds(x). Then that function is called every x milliseconds. If you want to do it once you should call the setTimeout that has the same params(a function and a quantity of milliseconds x), calling that function it will execute your method once after x milisecs. If you want to only show the content on the hover you can change the mouseIn/mouseOut functions, to do something as showing the content using a display="block" or use jQuery to do a slideUp/Down

Answer (score 0):

Use `onmouseover` event if you want the same behavior on mouse over of the image element.

```
<img id="image" name="image" src="images/img.png" border="0" 
       onclick="swapImage();" onmouseover="swapImage();"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I tried that and the problem there is that once you have hovered over the image it shows the content and to hide it you must move the cursor off the image and then back on.

Comment: try adding a onmouseout="swapImage();"

Comment: I tried that as well, the problem then is that once you click the image instead it hides the content and then when you move the cursor the content is visible when it should not be.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `:hover` selector is simple:

```css
#image:hover {
    background: url(your/image.png);
}
```